# How to calculate the number of possible combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 110 labels that can have one of three values: 1, 0 or "?"

The first time I receive a set of these labels, it could look something like this:

```
| LABEL1 | LABEL2 | LABEL3 | LABEL4 | ... | LABEL110 |
    0        1        0        ?       ?        ?
```

The second time it could look like this:

```
 | LABEL1 | LABEL2 | LABEL3 | LABEL4 | ... | LABEL110 |
     1        1        1        1       ?       ?
```

How do I calculate the total number of possible combinations?

I believe it is $110^3$ but I am not sure.

Comment: The problem is not very clear. Can you try to elaborate on what exactly do you want to count?

Comment: $110^3$ is if you have 3 labels with 110 values

Comment: Note that if instead of 110, you had 1 label with 3 possible values, there would be $3^1=3$ possibilities, not $1^3=1$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is $3^{110}$, which is way larger. You have to see it this way: for the first label, there are 3 possibilities. For the second as well; together, this makes $3 \cdot 3 = 3^2 = 9$. Continue this way up to the 110<sup>th</sup> label, and you will arrive at the solution $3^{110}$.